# Java-LSP freezes from Flymake error

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, java

I am very new to Java and have only been using an lsp for the past month or two. I have done some projects in Go, Python and Rust with lsp-mode and haven't had any problems. Now that I have been writing Java code though, my Emacs freezes any time I use java-lsp with Java.

I get the errors in my Flymake Log buffer whenever I open a Java file, and if I leave a Java file open for a while it freezes Emacs and if I try to edit a file it does the same. My Java-lsp config is below, and is just pulled from the README.

Java-lsp config

```
(require 'lsp-java)

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'lsp)
```

​

Flymake errors

```
Error \[flymake-proc [EmptySymTableException.java](https://EmptySymTableException.java)\]: NOMK: No buildfile (Makefile) found for <path>

Warning \[flymake [EmptySymTableException.java](https://EmptySymTableException.java)\]: Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because NOMK: No buildfile (Makefile) found for /<path>

Error \[flymake-proc [EmptySymTableException.java](https://EmptySymTableException.java)\]: init function flymake-proc-simple-make-java-init for <path> failed, cleaning up
```

I am currently using emacs 28.2 on Arch Linux. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After significant testing and bisecting my init file I found out the error was a problem with some kind of interaction between the hyperbole package and Java. Not sure what was happening exactly but it stopped happening when updating Hyperbole.